# Squid : Getting mac address of the machine making HTTP request in url_rewrite_program

Tags: proxy, squid, http-proxy

I am using `url_rewrite_program` written in `Python` to redirect url's based on following logic.

Logic will query the db and check whether the particular mac is authorized or not.

If he is authorized I would not change the URL.

If he is unauthorized I will redirect to login page.

---

My problem is that the input stream in `url_rewrite_program` only contains following data ( no mac information of the device making http_request).

```
http://www.google.com/ 10.10.10.2/10.10.10.2 - GET myip=- myport=3030
```

> How can I get the mac address?

The workaround I am using to get the mac address is to issue `arp -a`.

But it will be great if squid can provide the mac address to url_rewrite_program.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Scapy rather than subprocess and arp. But remember that MAC addresses do not survive routing, so the MAC you see might not be the client's MAC